# How to specific the resource ARN (Amazon Resource Name) in the state machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I follow this tutorial (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/analyzing-contact-center-calls-part-1-use-amazon-transcribe-and-amazon-comprehend-to-analyze-customer-sentiment/) to create a workflow using the state machine (Step Functions) in AWS,

Step 7 in this tutorial talks about '**Invoke Step Functions**', where they mentioned as I need to pass the ARN of the lamdba function which I am not clear

How to pass this resource ARN as parameter?

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html#amazon-states-language-task-state-specifying-resource-arns

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the lambda ARN from the lambda console and then follow this step as mentioned in the [Step functions documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-creating-lambda-state-machine.html). Change the params as per your config:

> In the State machine definition pane, add the following state machine
>   definition using the ARN of the Lambda function that you created
>   earlier, for example:

```
{
  "Comment": "A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using an AWS Lambda function",
  "StartAt": "HelloWorld",
  "States": {
    "HelloWorld": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:HelloFunction",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```